# Forward packet to specific port with scapy

Tags: python, scapy, packet

Is it possible to grab a packet destined to a different port and send it to another port? The idea is to make a port seem open or closed.

```
if pckt.haslayer(TCP):
    if str(pckt[TCP].dport) == "500":
        pckt[TCP].dport = 6698
        del pckt[IP].chksum
        del pckt[TCP].chksum
        sendp(pckt, verbose=False)
```

This is what I tried to do, but it does not work. My guess is that the computer is answering faster than scapy. I look around and some people seem to point to iptables, but I struggled using it. I've also tried NetfilterQueue but it seems it was abandoned and refuses to work on python3.10.

Can anyone advise?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do. You just want to send the copy of the sniffed packet which one destination port is 500 to the port 6698? You want to stop the packet with destination port 500 from sending and reroute it to the 6698 port?

Comment: Correct! The idea is to redirect a packet, either by copying it and sending it as response or modifying the original one before sending it back as a reply.

Consider the following: Send a SYN packet to port 500, the script catches it and forwards to the 6698 port, which is open. Making the attacker believe the port 500 is indeed open when in reality it is closed. I don't know if this is achievable.

Comment: I am not sure but I think that stopping the traffic by catching the packet is not possible in scapy. You can craft the packet in which you will send setuped flags to indicate that port 500 is open even though it is not but I don't have any other idea.